# Laplace equation with a strange Neumann boundary condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, laplacian, multigrid

[image]

We want to solve the Laplace equation on the above grid. But, I really have no idea about how to start. I think "discretization" is needed and the computer can solve that. Am I right? The Neumann boundary condition is $\frac{\partial u}{\partial N}=3$ on the really strange side $y=-1.4x+10.9$.

Also, at the point $P=(6,0)$, there is a discontinuity of boundary conditions. At this corner, $0.25x^2=9$ but $y+12=12$ and $9\neq 12$. Is this problem wrong?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. I am very sorry that I don't know much about what I am doing.

Comment: @gpmath Thanks.